# Mysql update values

Tags: mysql

I'm using two tables in the database. The first table looks like this:

```
   id    |   msg_id   |     user   |   date   
-------------------------------------------------
   01    |    122     |    user 1  | 2011-04-01
   02    |    453     |    user 2  | 2011-04-03
   03    |    124     |    user 3  | 2011-04-05
```

And the second table looks like this:

```
       id    |   msg_id   |     status   | 
   ----------------------------------------
       01    |      0     |       1      | 
       02    |      0     |       1      | 
       03    |     124    |       1      |
```

I want to update all the rows with the "0" value ("msg_id" column) in the second table based on msg_id records  from the first table.
Is it possible to do it with a single query?

The result should look like:

```
       id    |   msg_id   |     status   | 
   ----------------------------------------
       01    |    122     |       1      | 
       02    |    453     |       1      | 
       03    |    124     |       1      |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2
SET t2.msg_id=t1.msg_id
WHERE t1.id = t2.id and t2.msg_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE secondTable 
SET msg_id = (SELECT msg_id FROM firstTable WHERE firstTable.msg_id = secondTable.msg_id)
WHERE msg_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  table2 t2
JOIN    table1 t1
ON      t2.id = t2.id
SET     t2.msg_id = t1.msg_id
WHERE   t2.msg_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
UPDATE table2 t2  SET msg_id = (SELECT msg_id 
  FROM table1 t1 where t2.id = t1.id AND t2.msg_id=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE secondTable as st , firstTable as ft set st.msg_id = ft. msg_id WHERE ft.id = st.id
and st.msg_id = 0;
```